# how to run angular 4.6 application in Apache- tomcat server?

Tags: angular

i'm new at angular 4.6,
my Question is about how to run angular 4 application using Apache-tomcat server.

Answer (score 2):

Go to our app and run below command.

```
ng build --base-href=/angular/
```

http://www.thejavageek.com/2018/01/04/deploying-angular-app-tomcat/

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

Build project like:   ng build --prod --aot
*AOT is ahead of time compilation in angular.

Then in index.html in dist folder change href="/" to "./".

Then copy all the files to a folder(YOUR_APP_NAME) inside webapps folder and you are good to go.

Also, you can create your web.xml file inside WEB_INF directory for your application specific settings like errors, accessibility etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular CLI, you need to use

```
ng build --bh /appName/
```

If you are deploying for production, use `--prod`. When you use production parameter to build, angular uses production configurations like AOT.

for ref you can follow angular cli [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki).